# printing debug message from native C code to output

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone 8 in visual studio 2012 with native library written in C. I changed the debugger type of the startup project to native only. They used printf for debug message in C, but in output they are not printed.I tried  with  OutputDebugString() but not working(compile error) .Please help me out (note that it is .c file not .cpp).

Comment: `not working(compile error)` It is always a good idea to attach error message to your post

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that OutputDebugString doesn't work? In MSDN documentation they tell that it's compatible with Windows Runtime library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362(VS.85).aspx
Have you tried to include windows.h? What compiler error it gives you? Because that's the only way to print strings on a debugger in C (or C++, during native development on WinRT environment, that includes Windows 8 Modern UI and Windows Phone 8).

Comment: I written a single line in the library ::OutputDebugStringA("abcd") in place of printf("abcd"); it caused 8 errors which are not related to this line.(like syntex error; syntex error type, missing ';' before ':' etc)

Comment: @ashektowhid well, did you checked your syntax? attach [Short, Self Contained Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can see what's the problem.

Comment: actually, I am trying to debug pjsip opensource project from http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/branches/projects/winphone .There is  hundreds of files in this and this is why I didn't gave any code & I didn't change a single word of the working project. There are a lot of .C file calling printf function I just want to see them in my output.

Comment: I used in place of a printf call ::OutputDebugString("something") but compiler doesn't take this giving error : argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR". then I tried  ::OutputDebugStringA("something") compiler takes this but while building, gives 8 errors these errors doesn't look like meaningful so I didn't mention them.

Comment: Windows Runtime doesn't support ASCII or multibyte functions but only UNICODE. You should use ::OutputDebugStringW( L"Something" ), or include wchar.h and uses ::OutputDebugString( _T("Something") ) to make it cross compatible with ASCII. With UNICODE you should change your char* strings to wchar_t* or use TCHAR for cross compatible strings.

Comment: The problem remains. Same errors. The problem is somewhere else. They works in my .cpp files. but in .c files,causing same errors.